# How do I get XRange in LibreOffice calc from OnContentChanged event?

Tags: vba, libreoffice, basic

I need to get an object of type ooo.vba.excel.XRange on the OnContentChanged event in LibreOffice calc (7.1) for use in the Application.Intersect function. I've gone through IDL definition files / libreoffice help / blogs etc. but can't find any way of doing so. Does anyone know the equivalent of spreadsheet.Range[r,c] in LibreOffice calc?

```
Sub OnContentChange(event)
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oCellAddress As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim xRange As Object
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oCellAddress = event.getCellAddress()
    oSheet = oDoc.Sheets(oCellAddress.Sheet)
    
    xRange = oSheet.??(oCellAddress.Row, oCellAddress.Column) ' TODO get XRange NOT XCellRange
```

Comment: try `oSheet.getCellByPosition(...`

Comment: But it is (col,row) which is opposite of what you have.

Comment: You confused me with the phrase "for use in the Application.Intersect function". What *Application* are you talking about now? Did you mean [**.queryIntersection()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XCellRangesQuery.html#queryIntersection) method? It will be easier for us to help you if you tell us about the end goal, and not about a mistake in your way of achieving it. Otherwise, it will be the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Thank you @JohnSUN...Again! Application.Intersect is the Excel VBA 'equivalent'. queryIntersection was precisely what was needed.